# remote shutdown scripts

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a script to shutdown the computers in my classroom running Ubuntu 22.04. The script shuts down all the computers, but hangs and does not close.  If there something else I should add to the script or change. `hothost` is a file with the IP addresses of the computers I wish to turn off.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read host; do
   sshpass -p 123456 ssh "root@$host" shutdown -h now &
done < hothost
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use sshkeys instead of passwords. I would also shutdown -h +1 to schedule shutdown for 1 minute in the future, to give my script time to exit prior to executing the shutdown. If it still hangs i would recommend logging in to a targets main terminal when this script is shutting it down and see what is hanging

Comment: Thanks, will do.

Answer (score 1):

I put a < /dev/null in the script and it fixed the issue

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while read HOST ;
 do sshpass -p 123456 ssh "root@$HOST" "hostname; shutdown now " < /dev/null; 
 done < hothost
```